# Python: ContextManager-like for function alias

Tags: python, python-unittest

ContextManager is really useful and it's also make our code more readable, but it seems it only works if the given function is meant to be a context manager, otherwise it will fail (no `__exit__` or something else). I' wondering if we can use any function including those in libraries such as Django as a contextmanager, suppose the given code

```
self.assertEqual(Transaction.objects.filter(account=a, date=b, year=c).count(), 10)
self.assertEqual(Transaction.objects.filter(account=e, date=f, year=g).count(), 15)
self.assertEqual(Transaction.objects.filter(account=h, date=i, year=j).count(), 20)
```

Can be transformed into:

```
with Transaction.objects.filter as f:
    self.assertEqual(f(account=a, date=b, year=c).count(), 10)
    self.assertEqual(f(account=d, date=d, year=e).count(), 15)
    self.assertEqual(f(account=h, date=i, yearj).count(), 20)
```

The way I look at it is that the one below is much readable, cleaner and less verbose. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Just do:

```
f = Transaction.objects.filter
```

before your statements!

If you really wanted to use a context manager, you could write one that does what you want:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def alias(func):
    yield func

with alias(Transaction.objects.filter) as f:
    ...
```

Note that, however you do this, without an explicit `del` statement, `f` will still be around after the `with`.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem with this is if you have several parts that does similar thing (imagine there is Transaction, Book, User, etc) it will be very cluttered and most importantly, there's no way to tell you're done with `f` like you do when using context manager.

Comment: Added a potential solution.

Comment: Note: you can use `del` to "tell when you are done", although this needs an explicit statement.

Answer (score 4):

You're misunderstanding how the python `with` works (probably due to experience of Django Template's `{% with %}` block).

As mentioned in [PEP 343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/), the `with` statement allows you to easily abstract `try/finally` blocks. This is really useful for things such as IO, where, if something goes wrong, you want to make sure that you safely close the file no matter what.

In your example, you're really looking to just reduce the length of the variable, which is a nested child of both `Transaction` and `Transaction.objects`. In that case you can simple do.

```
fn = Transaction.objects.filter
```

Your follow-up question of "how do I invalidate the usage of `fn`... after we go out of the scope" is also a little bit mis-guided, as common usages of `with` don't necessarily destroy the variable's reference to the original object.

```
>>> with open("README.md") as f:
...     print f
...
<open file 'README.md', mode 'r' at 0x0055F860>
>>> f
<closed file 'README.md', mode 'r' at 0x0055F860>
>>>
```

To be honest, I'd suggest that you look for an alternative solution, as I think the semantics here are a little off. That said, if you *truly* want to do this, **and** mimic the unassignment as well, you'd need something like this:

```
class AliasContextManager(object):
    """
    Handle temporary function scope within a with block.
    """
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.fn = fn

    def proxy(self):
        """
        Create a proxy to our function, such that we can remove the reference
        on exit, and replace it with None.
        """
        def _proxy(*args, **kwargs):
            fn = getattr(self, "fn", None)
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        return _proxy

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.proxy()

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        del self.fn

alias = AliasContextManager
```

And here's how it can be used:

```
>>> with alias(sum) as fn:
...     print fn([1,2,3])
...     print fn([4,5,6])
6
15
>>> print fn([7,8,9])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 22, in <module>
    print fn([7,8,9])
  File "x.py", line 8, in _proxy
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: Yes, even though I'm aware that `with` statement is meant for that, but somehow I was expecting behavior of aliasing a function, the amazing thing about it is that it can invalidate the usage of `fn` or `x` right after we go out of the scope, whereas if I'm using `fn = Trans..`, there will be no clear clue when I'm done with it, and a lot of things can go messy later on.

Comment: OK @kecebongsoft even so I still don't think this is necessarily a good idea, I've added a solution that might help you. It'll also re-assign your scoped variable to `None` outside of the with. Hope that helps!